# C++ create and print deque

Tags: c++, pointers, deque

I'm tring to create a deque and list the elements in it. I've made two functions for this: create_queue and print_queue. I've sent the pointers (head and tail) as reference so I don't have to declare them globally.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Nod {
    int info;
    Nod* next, *back;
};

void create_queue(Nod*& p, Nod*& u)
{
    Nod *c = new Nod;
    cout << "c->info: "; cin >> c->info;
    if (!p)
    {
        p = c;
        p->back = NULL;
        p->next = NULL;
        u = p;
    }
    else
    {
        u->next = c;
        c->back = u;
        u = c;
        u->next = NULL;
    }
}

void print_queue(Nod*& p, Nod*& u)
{
    Nod *c = p;
    while (c) {
        cout << c->info << " ";
        c = c->next;
    }
}


int main()
{
    int n, i = 1;
    Nod *p, *u = new Nod;
    cout << "Nr nod: "; cin >> n;
    while (i <= n){
    create_queue(p, u);
    i++;
    }
    print_queue(p, u);
    getchar();
}
```

From what I understand from the debugger, I'm not able to access p->info.
What is the problem?

Answer (score -1):

To pass an object that can be modified to a function you don't need that ugly `Nod*&` (address of a reference!) type. Use a common pointer `Nod*` instead.